# How to display remaining textbox characters in a label in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, character

I'm not sure if I have the last bit right? I changed the max length of the textbox to 140. I can't seem to use `TextLength`. Help please?! I have this so far:

```
protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    characterCountLabel.Text = textBox.MaxLength - textBox.TextLength;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?...the wrong count?...or does your Label never get updated?  If the last one, make sure you have the TextChanged() event or your TextBox wired up to this method.

Comment: I'm getting a red squiggly line under `TextLength`

Comment: Do you use WinForms or WPF for your application? You may use (it is not the best approach, anyway) [`String.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) property of `textBox.Text`.

Comment: i'm using visual web developer 2010. ASP.net

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms? Well, try to use `textBox.Text.Length`.

Comment: okay! I'll try that now!

Comment: @Kristie Judd, Try my answer. If you have question comment them below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`characterCountLabel.Text` is in string format. So you might want to convert it before you set its value like this:

```
protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    characterCountLabel.Text = (textBox.MaxLength - textBox.Text.Length).ToString();
}
```

I think you are trying to display the remaining characters the user can input to your text box? I suggest that you can set the limit as constant like this:

```
protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        characterCountLabel.Text = (140 - textBox.Text.Length).ToString(); // in here 140 is your limit
    }
```

If you are using ASP.NET in C#. Don't limit yourself from using javascript [like in this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12509/Characters-Remaining-in-TextBox)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. My label is not displaying anything though.

Comment: What do you mean. Are you using WebForms? or WinForms?

Comment: I'm trying to make an active character remaining count. for example, on twitter. when you're typing a tweet, the characters remaining are displayed when you're typing. Am I able to do this?

Comment: Yes. Of course but I strongly suggest that you use javascript instead of `textBox_textChanged` method. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will be a better answer...

Header code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getCountDown() 
    {
        //Get the Textbox control
        var textField = document.getElementById("<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>");
        //Do the math of chars left and pass the value to the label
        document.getElementById('<%#Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = textField.maxLength - textField.value.length;
        return false;
    }        
</script>
```

ASP code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="729" Height="80px" 
                Width="591px" onkeyup="getCountDown();" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

It is important to set the `TextBox` and `Label` control's property as `ClientIDMode="Static"` otherwise the control name will not be found on the javascript.

CS code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

That's it for a `SingleLine` TextBox.

Now for a `MultiLine` `TextBox` you need to add this on your `Page_Load()` so the `maxLength` takes the `TextBox1.MaxLength` value.:

```
this.TextBox1.Attributes.Add("maxLength", TextBox1.MaxLength.ToString());
```

Also the `MaxLength` property of the `TextBox` doesn't work when is on `Multiline` mode so you need to add on your javascript `getCountDown()` function the following lines:

```
// Check if user is entering more than the limit of characters
if (textField.value.length >= textField.maxLength) {
    // Cut extra text
    document.getElementById("<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").innerHTML = textField.value.substring(0, textField.maxLength);
}
```

add them right after the `var textField = document.getElementById("<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>");` line. This is to prevent the user from entering more characters than the `MaxLength` value.

Pablo

Comment: Best answer , Best !@!@